# iOS 7 UIRefreshControl tintColor not working for beginRefreshing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, ios7

I'm trying to set a tintColor on my UIRefreshControl (building on iOS 7).
I enabled refreshing for the tableViewController in storyboard, then in my ViewController `viewDidLoad` method i did the following:

```
[self.refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

So now, when I pull to refresh, the color of the refresh control is red indeed:

[image: redSpiny]

I want my view to update automatically when it appears, so I did:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}
```

It didn't show the spinning wheel, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/16250679/1809736, I added

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

to force show it.
It shows it, but now it is back to default color:

[image]

If I try manually to pull to refresh afterwards, it is red.

I tried building it on iOS6 and it works as it should, so is that an iOS7 bug?

P.S.: it is not a problem with the simulator, I tried building it on device, same bug.

P.P.S: I built an example project, can you tell me if you have the same bug or if there is a problem in my code? Here is the link: http://d.pr/f/pGrV

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems to be an iOS 7 bug.

Comment: UIRefreshControl is verry buggy under iOS7. I suggest using an open source or living with the bugs for now. Make sure to open a bug report at https://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Ok, that's too bad.. Thanks!

Comment: It's almost like they ran out of time with iOS7. There are bugs with the `UISearchViewController` too. Hopefully a future update will fix this.

Comment: IOS 8 still has this bug... strange...

Comment: Also iOS9.  Did somebody find a solution?

Comment: Same on iOS 11 :(

Comment: Same on iOS 12 :(

Comment: Same on iOS 13 :(

Comment: Same on iOS 14 :( (yeah I know, no hope for this bug :-p)

Answer (score 54):

Hey just stumbled into this exact issue.

Interestingly I fixed my code by setting the contentOffset first then calling beginRefreshing

```
if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y == 0){
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}
```

You may want to animate this process:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^(void){
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height);
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}];
```

Hope this helps you.

W

Comment: this sometimes doesn't work because the point in offsetting the table is because it has some space to offset, but only after you call beginRefreshing… if you offset it before it won't have much to offset to!

Comment: Very important to call "beginRefreshing" after setting the contentOffset ! (at least on ios8)

Comment: I was stuck on this for a while but it turns out I was using [myTableView setContentOffset... animated:YES]. This was not working for me. Set the offset directly and use the UIView animation block as above instead.

Comment: The order of calls is indeed important. Weird issue deserving a comment "//???***" in the code documentation.

Comment: I was having trouble getting the attributedTitle to render properly - it would seem to jump. What I did is set it before the animation, with the proper string but with the text color set to clear. Then, after the beginRefreshing, I called it again but with the color set to (black or white). In any case, this works great in iOS 9.2!

Comment: There is a built-in method for animating content offset:
self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)

Answer (score 28):

SWIFT SOLUTION !
Insert the following code in the `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height)
self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
```

**Swift 3.1**

```
self.refreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.orange
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x:0, y:-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height)
self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
```

Comment: Thanks this fixes some issues for me when loading from `viewDidLoad`. The refreshcontrol had the wrong height and wrong color every first use.

Answer (score 8):

@william-george's answer set me in the right direction, but was giving me weird autolayout animation issues.

So here's the version that worked for me:

```
- (void)programaticallyRefresh {
    // Hack necessary to keep UIRefreshControl's tintColor
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1.0f) animated:NO];
    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
    [self refresh];
}
```

`-refresh` is the method tied to the `UIRefreshControl`.

Answer (score 7):

Add an extension for UIResfreshControl.

```
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually() {
        self.tintColor = UIColor.white
        if let scrollView = superview as? UIScrollView {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y:scrollView.contentOffset.y - frame.height), animated: false)
        }
        beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Comment: Comparing with another solutions, this is the one that worked and looked better implemented. :) Thanks Sefa and great trick.

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers are working for me correctly on iOS8, with the closest being @jpsim's answer but that still left an unsightly black refresh control during its fade-in animation (it would cross-fade between black and while over the course of the animation).

The solution that worked for me was to put this immediately after creating the refresh control in my viewDidLoad:

```
self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
self.refreshControl.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
...
self.refreshControlHeight = self.refreshControl.frame.size.height;
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -1) animated:NO];
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:NO];
```

Then to show the UIRefreshControl programmatically:

```
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.tableView.contentOffset.y-self.refreshControlHeight) animated:YES];
[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
```

I had to store the height of the refresh control, as while it was set for the first invocation, subsequent calls would have a 0 height.

Comment: Thank you, could you enlighten me on the fact that this only works with -1? I don't like magical numbers...

Comment: It's not a magic number, he's just changing the content offset by a negligible amount then changing it back.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for the tintColor issue: add this in viewDidLoad

```
[self.refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.refreshControl tintColorDidChange];
```

Now you have a white indicator when you call beginRefresh manually.

Answer (score 3):

SWIFT:

I am using Swift and > iOS8. Most of the described workarounds didn't work for me. That's how I got it working:

In viewDidLoad:

```
customRefreshControl.tintColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

The following doesn't have to be inside viewDidLoad. I put it in an extra function which get's called every time I update the tableView:

```
private func startRefreshControlAnimation() {

    self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -self.customRefreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)

    CATransaction.begin()
    self.customRefreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    CATransaction.commit()

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I combined some of the previous answers.  This works for me on iOS 9 and Swift 2:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let contentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0, delay: 0, options: .BeginFromCurrentState, animations: {
        print(self.tableView.contentOffset.y)
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, -self.refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: false)
        }, completion: { finished in
            self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
            self.tableView.setContentOffset(CGPointMake(0, contentOffset/2-self.refreshControl.frame.size.height), animated: true)
            self.refresh() // Code that refresh table data
    })        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I develop for iOS using Xamarin (C#) and came across the same issue.

I fixed the coloring issue, by setting the `AttributedTitle` of the `RefreshControl` :

```
private CGPoint originalOffset;
...
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
     base.ViewDidLoad ();
     ...
     originalOffset = TableView.ContentOffset; // Store the original offset of the table view
     RefreshControl = new UIRefreshControl (){ TintColor = UIColor.Red };
     RefreshControl.ValueChanged += ((s,e) => { Update (this, EventArgs.Empty); });
     // Hack so the TintColor of the RefreshControl will be properly set
     RefreshControl.AttributedTitle = new NSAttributedString ("Fetching data");
}
```

My Update method looks like this :

```
private async void Update(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
     try {
          TableView.UserInteractionEnabled = false;
          // I find -100 to be a big enough offset
          TableView.SetContentOffset (new CGPoint (0, -100), true);
          RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing ();
          ... // Fetch data & update table source 
          TableView.ReloadData ();
      } catch(Exception) {
          // Respond to exception
      } finally {
          // Put the offset back to the original
          TableView.SetContentOffset (originalOffset, true);
          RefreshControl.EndRefreshing ();
          TableView.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
      }
}
```

Once the `ViewDidAppear`, I call `Update` programmatically.
Before setting the attributed title, my spinner would've been black.
Now it has the proper red color.

It's worth noticing, that this 'hack/fix' also comes with a second bug.
The first time you refresh, you'll notice that the `AttributedTitle` is not displayed.
Refreshing a second (,third,fourth,...) time will display the title properly. But if you don't want a title, you just initialize it with an empty string, and this is not a big issue to you.

I hope this can be of use to others.

Answer (score 1):

this hack is very working

```
var refreshWasProgramBeginning: Bool = false

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if !refreshWasProgramBeginning {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, animations: {
            self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: -self.refreshControl.frame.height)
        }) { (_) in
            self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
            self.refreshWasProgramBeginning = true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am working with Xamarin C# (iOS 10) and found that a combination of all of these answers is what fixed it for me.

In my `ViewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
    RefreshControl = new UIRefreshControl();
    RefreshControl.TintColor = UIColor.White;
    RefreshControl.ValueChanged += OnRefresh;
    RefreshControl.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
```

And later I programmatically call the refresh animation in my `ViewDidAppear` with the following:

```
    BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        UIView.Animate(0, 0.2, UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState, () =>
        {
            TableView.SetContentOffset(new CGPoint(0, TableView.ContentOffset.Y - RefreshControl.Frame.Size.Height), true);
            RefreshControl.AttributedTitle = new NSAttributedString("");
        },
        () =>
        {
            RefreshControl.BeginRefreshing();
        });
    });
```

Note the setting of the attributed title and animation block were the parts I was missing for my `RefreshControl` to take my white tint color.

Thanks to all that have contributed to this question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug which occurs when calling `beginRefreshing()` on the refresh control right after setting its `tintColor` property (or calling it from `viewDidLoad()` (details [here](https://github.com/davbeck/RefreshTintFail)). There is an easy workaround however, by wrapping the `beginRefreshing()` call inside a `defer` statement (Swift 4):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    refreshControl.tintColor = .red
    defer {
        refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set manually content offset for your tableView/scrollView before begin spinning:

```
tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: tableView.contentOffset.y - (refreshControl.frame.size.height)), animated: true)
refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
......
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution** without adjusting content inset.

So you're going to hide original activity indicator replacing it with yours activity indicator (or custom view like LottieAnimationView).

```swift
import UIKit

final class CustomRefreshControl: UIRefreshControl {

    private let loaderView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: .zero)

    override init() {

        super.init(frame: .zero)
        setup()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.setup()
    }

    override func beginRefreshing() {

        super.beginRefreshing()
        self.loaderView.startAnimating()
    }

    override func endRefreshing() {

        super.endRefreshing()
        self.loaderView.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func didAddSubview(_ subview: UIView) {

        super.didAddSubview(subview)
        subview.alpha = subview === self.loaderView ? 1 : 0
    }
}

// MARK: - Private

private extension CustomRefreshControl {

    func setup() {

        self.tintColor = .clear // hides default indicator view only when user pulls
        self.addSubview(self.loaderView)
        self.loaderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.loaderView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            self.loaderView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
            self.loaderView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32),
            self.loaderView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 32)
        ])

        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.beginRefreshing), for: .valueChanged)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the tintColor of your UIRefreshControl in viewWillAppear.

Answer (score 0):

i found some Work Around i hope it works for you

```
 [_TBL setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0,_TBL.contentOffset.y-_refreshControl.frame.size.height) animated:YES];
[_refreshControl performSelector:@selector(beginRefreshing) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.25];
[self getLatestUpdates];
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a drop-in [UIRefreshControl+beginRefreshing category](https://gist.github.com/hlung/0ff9c310ead2ca9de3a2) that fixes this issue.

In brief, it fixes tintColor issue and manually tableView adjust contentOffset to make sure the refresh control is visible. Please try :)

Answer (score 0):

When I set

```
tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl
```

several times where refreshControl is a different instance each time, I had the issue when refresh control color was always black and setting tint color to a different value didn't help.

So that I set `tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl` only once and when I need to hide it I set alpha value, more details in this thread:

[How do I "hide" a UIRefreshControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480424/how-do-i-hide-a-uirefreshcontrol/54461766#54461766)

Answer (score 0):

Using `UIView.animate` didn't work for me on Swift 4.

Here's what I ended up using

```swift
extension UIRefreshControl {
    func beginRefreshingManually(with scrollView: UIScrollView, isFirstTime: Bool) {
        if self.isRefreshing { return }

        // Workaround: If we call setContentOffset on the first time that the screen loads
        // we get a black refreshControl with the wrong size.
        // We could just set the scrollView.contentOffset everytime, but it does not animate the scrolling.
        // So for every other time, we call the setContentOffset animated.
        if isFirstTime {
            scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.frame.size.height)
        } else {
            scrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -self.frame.size.height), animated: true)
        }
        self.beginRefreshing()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling with this issue myself for a couple days now.
This is how I fixed it on my project:

I have a property on my VC for my refreshControl:

```
private lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refresh = UIRefreshControl()
    refresh.tintColor = UIColor.yellow
    refresh.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .valueChanged)
    return refresh
}()
```

On my `viewDidAppear` method, I was using

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.frame.height), animated: true)
     refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
}
```

Well, turns out that if you set the `animated` property of `setContentOffset` to false, the refresh control tint color appears correctly from the very first time...

**Corrected code, working for me:**

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
     super.viewDidAppear(animated)

     tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: -refreshControl.frame.height), animated: false)
     refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
 }
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Force the setTintColor to run in the main thread. (Main thread updates the ui).

```
[[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {
    [self.refreshControl setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];
}];
```