# Completely disabling UIRefreshControl - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uirefreshcontrol

I have a tableview that is refreshable with a `UIRefreshControl`. It works fine.

The catch is that I wish to disable the `UIRefreshControl` when I click an `Edit` button (which is a `UIBarButton`). I am having extreme difficulties in trying to disable `UIRefreshControl` completely. I've gotten it to the point where the content of my table is definitely not being refreshed (which is good), but the user is still able to pull down and reveal the spinny-symbol, which then displays briefly. Is there any way I can hide this spinny-symbol?

I've tried so many things: `refreshControl.endRefreshing()`, `refreshControl.isHidden = true`, `refreshControl.removeFromSuperview()`, `refreshControl = nil`...

Here's some of my code. (`isInEditMode` is an instance variable that is true when `Edit` is tapped and false when `Done` is tapped. I am confident that this boolean is set properly, so I don't believe that's the problem.)

```
func refreshTable(sender: UIRefreshControl) {

    if !isInEditMode {

        self.refreshControl.beginRefreshing()
        refreshProfile() 

    // this works exactly as I want it to

    }

    else {
        refreshControl.endRefreshing()
        // OR refreshControl.isHidden = true
        // OR refreshControl = nil
        // OR refreshControl.removeFromSuperview()

        // refreshProfile() not called, so table doesn't update, but the user can still pull down and the spinny icon shows. I do not want this. 
    }



}
```

EDIT: I tried all of the solutions set forth in [How do I "hide" a UIRefreshControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480424/how-do-i-hide-a-uirefreshcontrol), and none of them solved my issue. It may be because that post is quite old--2013. (Or because something about the way I'm using `UIRefreshControl` is different. The primary solution set forth in that post is to set the `UIRefreshControl` to `nil` after `endRefreshing()`. This did not work for me. I also tried the hacky solution suggested of setting the tint of the `UIRefreshControl` to `clear`. And, as outline above, I also tried `isHidden` and `removeFromSuperview()`. Another factor distinguishing my post from that other post is that all of those answers for Objective-C, whereas I am interested in Swift 3. (Although I'm pretty sure I was able to translate the suggestions on that thread to Swift. That's beside the point though, since none of them worked for me.)

Comment: `sender.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`

Comment: Didn't work :( This is a very odd situation.

Comment: I tried all the solutions set forth in the post linked to by @Sneak, and none of them worked for me. That is a pretty old post (2013)...perhaps things have changed? It's all very mysterious.

Comment: i would say that if removing `UIRefreshControl` from the view didn't work then there is some magic in there

Comment: Is it possible to accidentally have 2 `UIRefreshControl`s? I have one as an instance variable. Does tableview come with one already? (Alternatively, maybe I'm adding it back somewhere else in my code right after I remove it...I'll look into that.)

Comment: @mlecoz **First of all**, are you using a UITableViewController or a UITableView inside a UIViewController? **Second**, how can your refreshcontrol stil work if you set it to = nil ? **Third**, Did you add the refreshcontrol by code? If so, Where did you add it?  I would like to know? I have removed the duplicate flag, since this seems to be an issue with your code.

Comment: 1) UITableView in UIViewController. 2) I have absolutely no clue. The code I gave above is quite a simplified version of what I'm doing, so I think there are some other places I could have messed up. I've been looking it over for the past 5 hours or so, though, setting breakpoints and such, but it's still very mysterious to me. The spinny-thing is indeed part of the UIRefreshControl, right? 3) Yes, I added `refreshControl` by code in `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: If you're adding it in `viewWillAppear` you could definitely have multiple refresh controls. You should only need to add it in `viewDidLoad` and whenever you want to add it back after you've finished editing.

Comment: @DaveWeston Thats the problem right there. viewWillAppear gets called multiple times. Add it as an answer so he can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the conversation in comments it seems like the answer is that multiple `UIRefreshControl`s are being added to the `UITableView` in `viewDidAppear`.

The refresh control property on the view controller refers to the latest one added, and that one likely is being disabled properly. However, any previously added refresh controls would still be retained by the table view, even though the view controller no longer has a reference to them.

The fix is to only add the refresh control once, during `viewDidLoad` and disable it, but leave it in the table view when switching to edit mode so it can be re-enabled when leaving edit mode.