# How to change color of UIRefreshControl when it is refreshing?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uirefreshcontrol

I want to change color of UIRefreshControl when it in "refreshing" state. It works fine on iOS 6, but on iOS 7 it doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026351/ios-7-uirefreshcontrol-tintcolor-not-working-for-beginrefreshing

Answer (score 1):

It's not my code I've found it a months ago somewhere and it works for me.

```
CGRect refreshFrame = self.tableView.bounds;
refreshFrame.origin.y = -frame.size.height;
UIView* refreshBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:refreshFrame];
refreshBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]; //<- Here you choose what colour you want

[self.tableView insertSubview:refreshBackgroundView atIndex:0];
```

Comment: thank you, but I want to change color of spinner not background color