# Sliding a UITableView down when search bar and scope bar appear

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios9, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    float searchBarBottom = self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height;
    // searchBarBottom = 200.0;
    CGPoint offset = CGPointMake(0, searchBarBottom);
    self.tableView.contentOffset = offset;

    return YES;
}
```

I hit the search bar which appears above my table view and the search bar controller shows the search bar with a cancel button on the top line and my scope bar below. I want the table view to slide down below the scope bar but above isn't working. How does this get fixed?

Comment: Apparently in ios 9 you need to call [self.tableView beginUpdates] - see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20383030/665557

Comment: It's `[self.refreshControl beginRefreshing]`. If you call `beginUpdates` you will also need to call `endUpdates` after you finished

Comment: what is the refresh control? i just want my table view to move down when the scope bar gets added in

Comment: I'm just saying that you are pointing the wrong link