# using of UIRefreshControl in uitableview

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

i am using UIRefreshControl to refresh my table when the user scroll the table down. that is working fine.

now i am using timer to auto refresh the table after some time, what i want is to:

Show the refreshing icon while the table is refreshing automatically without user interaction.

i used this code:

```
 in viewDidLoad:
{
    UIRefreshControl *refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(refresh:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [self.tableView addSubview:refreshControl];
}

- (void)refresh:(UIRefreshControl *)refreshControl
{
    [self doUpdate];
    [refreshControl endRefreshing];
}
```

any help will be appreciated .

Comment: And the problem is...? (Also where is the timer code?)

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082149/how-do-i-programatically-slide-the-uitableview-down-to-reveal-the-underlying-uir

Comment: Why aren't you calling `[super viewDidLoad];` ?

Answer (score 1):

First you need to use the tableview controller setter for the control, not just add it as a subviews. Then, you start the refresh with 'tableViewController.refreshControl beginRefresh'.

```
UITableViewController *tableViewController;
tableViewController.refreshControl = [UIRefreshControl new];
...
[tableViewController.refreshControl beginRefresh];
```